# Python editor that lets you paste pictures in your program

Tags: windows, images, python

And has those images do nothing/affect the code not at all?

Purpose: maybe I google something, find a screenshot, and I want to just shove it into the program so I can find it later easily. Or say I get an error and for convenience just want to snipping tool the error, paste it somewhere in the program and figure it out later.

Think of how Mathematica lets you paste images in the code. Except now take away all functionality of images being variables or symbols and have images do absolutely nothing. Just like when you paste an image.

So effectively, when you run the program the pictures would just be ignored.

Preferably would like a darker colored editor and would be willing to pay 60$ ish.

I use a Windows 10 laptop.

If this does not exist, what would be the easiest way to create this?

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to get what you are asking for will soon be to simply work in [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) & [iPython](http://ipython.org/).

- Your code is in a set of cells but you can also have cells of markdown.
- You can mix code & images, links, etc., in a single Jupyter notebook
- Th capability was added to Jupyter as [pull 621](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/621) which should be in included in Jupyter 5.0 - ***no due date just yet!***
- Gratis & Open Source

While this functionality is not generally available yet you can get used to working in Jupyter now and it already has mechanisms for displaying images, etc., from external files and web locations or you can become a tester for the new functionality.